# Competition practise task (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm

Not sure if it's the best title. The explanation of what the program is suposed to do is below, my version only works with the first example but it doesn't work in the second when you get for example 1 1 3 1 1 2 because i can't figure out a good way to handle so much variations especially if K is bigger than 3 and the limit is 50. My version:

```
N, K, M = map(int, input().split())
niz = list(map(int, input().split()))
nizk = list(range(1, K+1))
izlazi = []

for r in range(0, M):
    operacija = list(map(int, input().split()))
    index = 0

    if operacija[0] == 2:
        nizkk = []
        for z in range(0, len(nizk)):
            if nizk[z] in niz:
                continue
            else:
                izlazi.append(-1)
                break

        for p in range(0, N):
            if niz[p] not in nizkk:
                nizkk.append(niz[p])
                nizkk.sort()

            if nizkk == nizk:
                index = p
                izlazi.append(index+1)
                break
            else:
                continue
    else:
        index, repl = map(int, operacija[1:])
        niz[index - 1] = repl

print(izlazi)
```

In the first line of the input there should be N, K, M (1 <= N, M <= 100k, 1 <= K <= 50, you don't need to actually check this the numbers that are tested will always be in those ranges). In the second line of input you put a list of numbers which are the lenght of N you entered earlier. M is the number of operations you will do in the following lines of input. There can be 2 operations. If you enter 1 p v(p = index of number you want to replace, v the number you replace it with) or if you enter 2 it needs to find the shortest array of numbers defined by range(1, K+1) in the list of numbers you entered in line 2 and possibly changed with operation 1. If it doesn't exist it should output -1 if it does it should output lenght of numbers in the array you look in(numbers can be like 2, 1, 3 if you're looking for 1, 2, 3, also if you're looking for 1, 2, 3 etc and you have 2, 1, 1, 3 as the shortest one that is the solution and it's lenght is 4). Also the replacement operation doesnt count from 0 but from 1. So watch out when managing lists.

These are the examples you can input in the program ulaz = input, izlaz = ouput:
[image]

Comment: If you described the task correctly, then second test is incorrect. [1,2,3,2,1,1] after replacing second  element on 1(command 1 2 1) is [1,1,3,2,1,1] and finding min length sequence that contains [1,2,3] gives us 4(first four elements), and test expects 3.

Comment: You understood it correctly, but if there are ellements before the key sequence(1,2,3) they are ignored, or after, only if things such as 3,1,1,2 occur the solution is 4 or whatewer number is the case. But key sequences can also be in theory from 1 up to 50 so it can get very complicated and i don't have a universal solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following idea:
Min length sequence either starts from first element or does not contain first element and hence equals to min length of the same sequence without first element.
So we have recursion here.
For sequence [1,1,3,2,1,1] and [1,2,3] we will have:
Min length from start element [1,1,3,2,1,1] is 4
Min length from start element __[1,3,2,1,1] is 3
Min length from start element ____[3,2,1,1] is 3
Min length from start element ______[2,1,1] is -1
Can stop here.
Result is minimum for [4,3,3] = 3

You have already implemented the part for min length, if it starts from the first element. Need now extract it as a function and create a recursive function.

Some metacode:

> function GetMinLength(seq)
>    {
>     minLengthFromFirstElement = GetMinLenthFromFirstElement(seq)
>     minLengthFromRest = GetMinLength(seq[1:]) //recusive call
>     return Min(minLengthFromFirstElement, minLengthFromRest )//-1 results should not count, add extra code to handle it
>    }

Unfortunately I don't know python, but I can provide code on F# in case you need it.

**EDIT**:
Try this:

```
N, K, M = map(int, input().split())
niz = list(map(int, input().split()))
nizk = list(range(1, K+1))
izlazi = []

def GetMinLengthStartingFromFirstElement(seq):
    nizkk = []
    for z in range(0, len(seq)):
        if seq[z] in nizk:
            continue
        else:
            return -1

    for p in range(0, len(seq)):
        if seq[p] not in nizkk:
            nizkk.append(seq[p])
            nizkk.sort()

        if nizkk == nizk:
            index = p
            return index+1
        else:
            continue
    return -1

def GetMinLength(seq):
    if len(seq) == 0: 
        return -1
    else:
        curMinLength = GetMinLengthStartingFromFirstElement(seq)
        if curMinLength == -1:
            return -1
        minLengthFromRest = GetMinLength(seq[1:])
        if minLengthFromRest > -1:
            return min(curMinLength,minLengthFromRest)
        else:
            return curMinLength;


for r in range(0, M):
    operacija = list(map(int, input().split()))
    index = 0

    if operacija[0] == 2:
        minLength = GetMinLength(niz)
        izlazi.append(minLength)
    else:
        index, repl = map(int, operacija[1:])
        niz[index - 1] = repl

print(izlazi)
```

Comment: I think i understand what you mean, at the part where i get the minLenghtFromFirstElement i should put my for loop with p variable into the GetMinLenght function? But then I'm not sure how minLenghtFromRest is supossed to work, a bit more detailed explanation would be great? Thanks for helping out!

Comment: @simon101 check my edit, I think code tells better:)

Comment: I figured it out :D. Thanks a lot!